# Sine Wave generation - get Y axis

Tags: python, trigonometry

I'm trying to create an infinite loop that will output the Y axis of a sine wave, and want to use variables specifying the amplitude of the wave, frequency, and resolution. Where frequency is the number of full sine waves in a second like electrical AC frequency.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from time import sleep
from math import sin

amplitude=100
frequency=0.01
resolution=0.01

while True:
    y = <Sine wave math>
    print str(y)
    sleep(resolution)
```

I need help with the math and getting the resolution part right.

Comment: From math import sin?

Comment: Added that import. My problem is I don't know how to use it at all.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions

Comment: Are you able to write down a formula for y given x, and need help translating it into code?  Or do you not know how to write the formula?  In other words, is this a programming question or a mathematics question?

Comment: @SamCraig Thank you for that, but it is a foreign language to me, I just don't get it. I think that this code is close to what I want but minus the sound output: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/217024/creating-and-playing-a-sine-wave-sound-python

Comment: @PaulCornelius It's a mathematics question, I am an experienced coder. I don't know enough about what math I need to convert it to code.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best place for a mathematics question, but it isn't hard, so here you go.

sin(x) is a function that makes a wave. Its period, or the distance you go to get a full wave, is 2 * pi. To change the period to match your frequency, you have to multiply the x in sin(x) by a constant equal to 2 * pi * f, or have sin(2 * pi * f * x).

To change the amplitude of the wave, multiply it by the amplitude. So if you have amplitude A, you want A * sin(x)

I don't know what you are referring to as frequency.

Overall, what you want is A * sin(2 * pi * x).

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research and tweaking, this is what I've come to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from time import time,sleep
from math import sin,pi

frequency = 1
amplitude = 100
resolution = 0.01

def sineCalc(time,frequency,amplitude):
    factor = pi * frequency
    sin_seg = sin(time * factor)
    value = amplitude * sin_seg
    return value

while True:
    #Get y value based on current time.
    value = sineCalc(time(),frequency,amplitude)
    print str(value)
    sleep(resolution)
```

Comment: You can shorten this to `return amplitude * sin(time * pi * frequency)`.  For a full description, you can add [phase and offset](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Phase_and_Frequency): `return amplitude * sin(time * pi * frequency + phase) + offset`. cos(x) is for instance a phase shifted sin(x).